# What is the difference between static and dynamic seals?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

What is the difference between static and dynamic seals and  How much leakage is allowed past each seal?

Answer (score 3):

Generically speaking:

- A static seal is a seal between two surfaces that don't move relative
  to each other.
- A dynamic seal is a seal between two surfaces that do move relative to
  each other.

The amount of allowed leakage depends on the application.